# <ul> <li> aligning issue, different sized images

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have ul with following structure

```
<div class="gal">
<ul>
        <li>
            <a rel="lightbox[imgs]" href="http://192.168.0.204/CAPW/uploads/materials_pics/5fdc91f1f2e9471ca375d346d3558757.jpg">
                <img width="100" height="100" class="imgclass" src="http://192.168.0.204/CAPW/uploads/materials_pics/5fdc91f1f2e9471ca375d346d3558757_thumb.jpg">
            </a>    
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="lightbox[imgs]" href="http://192.168.0.204/CAPW/uploads/materials_pics/d3a43711dee8a4331f14329d40ed6314.jpg">
                <img width="100" height="100" class="imgclass" src="http://192.168.0.204/CAPW/uploads/materials_pics/d3a43711dee8a4331f14329d40ed6314_thumb.jpg">
            </a>    
        </li>
        <li>
            <a rel="lightbox[imgs]" href="http://192.168.0.204/CAPW/uploads/materials_pics/836bdef9b8ec56c0a88386760efb1f90.png">
                <img width="100" height="100" class="imgclass" src="http://192.168.0.204/CAPW/uploads/materials_pics/836bdef9b8ec56c0a88386760efb1f90_thumb.png">
            </a>    
        </li>

        </ul>
```

because I have different image thumb sizes I can't set width and height to `<li>` . Please refer to the screen-shot. It is not aligned properly[image]

The CSS used

```
<style type="text/css">
    .gal ul li {
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
        position: relative; 
        float: left;
        list-style:none;
    }

    .imgclass {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 15px 0;
        padding: 2px;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    .gal {
        margin:0 auto;
        width: 850px;
        text-align:center;
    }

    </style>
```

My problem is how avoid that overlapping the small-size images

Comment: can you post the css you've got so far?

Comment: I'm not clear on what, specifically, you're trying to align. Are you referring to the smaller thumbs that appear at the far right? How do you want them aligned if so?

Comment: maybe you can tell us what is your css?

Comment: please show an screen shot of your desire outcome

Comment: i need to align the smaller images also one by one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of floating the `li` elements, have them `display: inline;` then to counteract the "whitespace in HTML" link trailing you can have the `<a>` `display:inline-block` and then you will be able to set that `vertical-align: middle`

### [Example Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/rHfeQ/)

CSS:

```
.gal ul li {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative; 
    display: inline; /* changed from float */
    list-style:none;
}

.gal ul li a {display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;} /* added */

.imgclass { /* no need to float these **/
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 0;
}
.gal {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 850px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "display: inline-block". Not sure if it will work in all browser, there is problem in older firefox ( http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fs9RU/